# Eliminar etiqueta style de varios label que se encuentran dentro de un div (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como el título lo dice, quiero eliminar la etiqueta `style` del siguiente código mediante `JQuery`.

Código:

```
<div id="action_ligne" class="action_ligne">
    <label class="lbl obligatorio checked" style="color: red;">Code postal</label>
    <label class="obligatorio checked" maxlength="30" id="val_CL_ZIP" style="color: red;">NW8 9AY</label>
</div>
```

Olvidé aclarar que esto se encuentra dentro de un documento html bastante extenso por lo que no son los únicos label dentro del dom

Answer (score 1):

Veo que ambas etiquetas comparten la clase **obligatorio**, entonces a partir de ahí puedes hacerlo así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".obligatorio").removeAttr("style");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="action_ligne" class="action_ligne">
    <label class="lbl obligatorio checked" style="color: red;">Code postal</label>
    <label class="obligatorio checked" maxlength="30" id="val_CL_ZIP" style="color: red;">NW8 9AY</label>
</div>
```

También ambos son etiquetas **label**, así que lo puedes hacer también así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("label").removeAttr("style");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="action_ligne" class="action_ligne">
    <label class="lbl obligatorio checked" style="color: red;">Code postal</label>
    <label class="obligatorio checked" maxlength="30" id="val_CL_ZIP" style="color: red;">NW8 9AY</label>
</div>
```

Tomando como regerencia el id del div padre:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#action_ligne").find("label").each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr("style");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="action_ligne" class="action_ligne">
        <label class="lbl obligatorio checked" style="color: red;">Code postal</label>
        <label class="obligatorio checked" maxlength="30" id="val_CL_ZIP" style="color: red;">NW8 9AY</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Olvidé aclarar que esto se encuentra dentro de un documento html bastante extenso por lo que no son los únicos label dentro del dom

Comment: Puedes hacerlo tomando de referencia el id="action_ligne" que es el id padre.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría así de simple:

```
$('label').removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza [`.removeAttr(attrName)`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) que elimina un atributo del un elemento html:

```js
function eliminarStyle()
{
 $("#action_ligne label:last").removeAttr("style");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="action_ligne" class="action_ligne">
    <label class="lbl obligatorio checked" style="color: red;">Code postal</label>
    <label class="obligatorio checked" maxlength="30" id="val_CL_ZIP" style="color: red;">NW8 9AY</label>
</div>

<button onclick="eliminarStyle()">Eliminar style</button>
```

Comment: Olvidé aclarar que esto se encuentra dentro de un documento html bastante extenso por lo que no son los únicos label dentro del dom

Comment: Lo que buscas es eliminar el atributo `style` y hay lo tienes. Ya en ese caso tienes que adaptar el codigo a tus necesidades.